# Exception while creating WSDL2JAVA in Axis2

Tags: soap, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am trying to create a Java stub from a WSDL file in the command prompt. This is my command to convert WSDL to a Java stub file:

```
WSDL2Java -Eosv -uri  MyfileName.wsdl.
```

But I am getting this exception and I don't know how to resolve it. Can anyone help me to find out, how to solve this error?

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing WSDL
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerationEngine.java:156)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
>   Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurr
>   ed trying to resolve schema referenced at 'http://www.example/Example_Service/Service.svc?xsd=xsd1', relative to '
>   file:/D:/axis2-1.4.1/bin/MyFileName.wsdl'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.readInTheWSDLFile(CodeGenerationEngine.java:288)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerationEngine.java:111)
>           ... 2 more

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the exception, it searches for a file in below path.

D:/axis2-1.4.1/bin/MyFileName.wsdl

Make sure your file is in above location or put the http URL of wdsl file where the web service is hosted in your command.